# OpenLayers.Format.WMSCapabilities() is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, openlayers

When I try to do

> var ww = new OpenLayers.Format.WMSGetCapabilities();

I have an error that says:

> TypeError: OpenLayers.Format.WMSCapabilities is not a constructor

Which is a lie, because that exists in manual. 
I have version 2.13 of OpenLayers 
Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had to append script

> openlayers/OpenLayers/Format/WMSCapabilities.js

Anyway, I can't use this class because I have some problems with compatibility

> uncaught exception: Can't find a WMSCapabilities parser for version 1.1.1